# What's the equivalent of ExitThread(ExitCode) and GetExitCodeThread in C# & .net?

Tags: c#, multithreading, exit, exit-code

Reading the VS2008 help file I've figured out that the clean way of exiting a thread (in .net) is either by using a return statement (in C#) or letting the thread reach the end of the method.

However, I have not found a method or property that would allow me to set the thread's exit code nor a way to retrieve it (as it is done using the Win32 API).  Therefore, the question is, how do I do this using C# and .net ?

Thank you for your help,

John.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason the underlying Win32 thread primitives aren't exposed is to prevent managed code from relying on them. The CLR team is always working on ways to optimize thread usage, and that includes no guarantees about 1:1 managed:unmanaged thread mapping (see "Note" on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx), for instance). If you really want to do it anyway, you'll need to set up P/Invoke wrappers that use an unmanaged thread handle from Win32 GetCurrentThread(), or hook into the thread mapping process yourself with a custom host. I wouldn't recommend either, unless you absolutely have to interop with something that uses thread exit codes and isn't managed code-aware. Figure out another way to smuggle state info around if you can do it all managed (or use [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) to abstract up a level from bare threads).

Comment: nitzmahone, thank you for the reply and the links.  Given that there isn't a 1:1 correspondence between managed threads and O/S threads, I think that Pinvoking ExitThread and GetExitCodeThread won't be a reliable solution.  I am considering deriving a new thread class from Thread that adds an exit code along with the appropriate methods to set it and retrieve it.  My concern is that since the retrieval of the exit code would happen after the thread has terminated, the GC may have disposed of the thread object before the exit code is retrieved.  Is there a way to guarantee that won't happen ?

Comment: I doubt you'll get good results there either- Thread is sealed, and for good reason. If you're considering building something that doesn't use the Win32 exit code mechanism, why not use one of the higher level constructs that already exist for tracking logical thread status (aforementioned TPL, etc)? Alternatively, you could do something as simple as a static dictionary of managed thread IDs and  "exit codes"- guaranteed to live as long as you want. Don't know all the details of your project, but it sounds like you're trying to make life harder than it needs to be...

Comment: The real problem is that I am just learning .net and C#.  I am very knowledgeable in the plain Windows API, as a result, I try to match what I know about using the WinAPI to doing the same in .net and C#. Obviously, this method has its "problems" but it is usually good.  In this case, it sounds like I just have to learn more to figure out how to do things the .net way. Thank you for your help and suggestions.  John.

Comment: You'll curse the Win32 way once you do something real with TPL. Best of luck on your journey... :)

Comment: I'll make sure to check out TPL once I'm done learning the basics. Thank you :-)